# DatabaseNotClosed Exception - List View Scrolling

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, adapter

I have a list view populated by an adapter reading from SQLite database. When I scroll down in the list on screen I get the following error. I also get the same error when switching to another tab in the application (it is a tab based app).

close() was never explicitly called on database 
DatabaseNotClosedException : Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here.

Does anyone know why this is happening ? I have posted the main and adapter class files below.

Main Class :

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {

private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homeaz);

    ListView yourList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()

    {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                        Log.e("onClick",""+arg3);
                        Intent i = new Intent(Home.this,DetailView.class);
                        i.putExtra(DataBaseHelper.ID, arg3);
                        // Activity returns an result if called with startActivityForResult

                        /**Home.this.finish();*/
                        startActivity(i);

                        }   
    });


    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

} catch (IOException ioe) {

    throw new Error("Unable to create database");

}

try {

    myDbHelper.openDataBase();

}catch(SQLException sqle){

    throw sqle;

}

try {

    Cursor cursor = getPlaces();
    showPlaces(cursor);

}

finally {

myDbHelper.close();

}
}

private static String ORDER_BY = NAME + " ASC";

private Cursor getPlaces() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;

}

private void showPlaces(Cursor cursor) {

    MyCustomAdapterClass adapter = new MyCustomAdapterClass(this,cursor, true); setListAdapter(adapter); 

}
```

Adapter Class :

```
public class MyCustomAdapterClass extends CursorAdapter {

public MyCustomAdapterClass(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
}

@Override

public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Area")));
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AddressLine1")));
switch (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))) {
case 1:
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture1);
break;
case 2:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture2);
break;
case 3:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture3);
break;
case 4:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture4);
break;
case 5:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture5);
break;
case 6:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture6);
break;
case 7:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture7);
break;
case 8:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture8);
break;
case 9:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture9);
break;
case 10:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture10);
break;
case 11:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture11);
break;
case 12:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture12);
break;
case 13:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture13);
break;
case 14:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture14);
break;
case 15:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture15);
break;
case 16:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture16);
break;
case 17:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture17);
break;
case 18:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture18);
break;
case 19:
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Logo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.picture19);
break;
case 20:
```

Log :

> 09-10 18:44:25.495: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.Beutelkind.Database/.DetailView (has extras) }
> 09-10 18:44:25.665: DEBUG/dalvikvm(415): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4966 objects / 284992 bytes in 66ms
> 09-10 18:44:26.284: DEBUG/dalvikvm(415): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 300 objects / 14840 bytes in 56ms
> 09-10 18:44:27.435: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.Beutelkind.Database/.DetailView: 1888 ms (total 1888 ms)
> 09-10 18:44:28.725: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.Beutelkind.Database/.Main }
> 09-10 18:44:28.825: INFO/Database(415): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
> 09-10 18:44:28.825: ERROR/Database(415): sqlite3_open_v2("/mnt/sdcard/DatabaseC.sqlite", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
> 09-10 18:44:29.535: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.Beutelkind.Database/.Main: 781 ms (total 781 ms)
> 09-10 18:44:32.405: DEBUG/dalvikvm(415): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2748 objects / 167024 bytes in 63ms
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415): Releasing statement in a finalizer. Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor: SELECT DISTINCT _id, Name, Description, Area, Postcode, AddressLine1, OpeningTimes, NearestTube, Cos
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:62)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at com.Beutelkind.Database.DetailView.populateFields(DetailView.java:79)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at com.Beutelkind.Database.DetailView.onCreate(DetailView.java:70)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 09-10 18:44:32.455: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(415):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.Beutelkind.Database/databases/DatabaseC.sqlite' 
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:540)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at com.Beutelkind.Database.DetailView.populateFields(DetailView.java:77)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at com.Beutelkind.Database.DetailView.onCreate(DetailView.java:70)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 09-10 18:44:32.475: ERROR/Database(415):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: That's very weird, could you please provide the stacktrace of this error?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've pasted the log above - apologies if not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy one, you are not closing your database handles. For instance, you open a cursor in getPlaces but never close it when done using it, nor the db object from where it came.

Comment: Thanks. How do I fix it ? Just add finally statements and then close ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to close the temporary db object as well and if you do then your cursor won't return any results. I would move that temporary db just aside your helper instead of retrieving it every time. Then close your cursor as soon as you are done with it, and close the db just before closing your helper

Comment: I take you meant just outside ?

Comment: I mean 
private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase myDB;